# div text moving slightly upward even when ul child display set to none

Tags: html, css

I'm a bit new to CSS so forgive me for any shortcomings on my side but I can't seem to find the solution for this problem anywhere else. I'm sure it is very trivial as I haven't changed too much to the code before it went wrong.

So I have made this website's navbar which has 8 different div on it and they are equally spaced with each other. I want to have a drop down when mouse hovers on some of them. Anyway, before I created a list(or comment it) as a child of this div the `ABOUT US` seems to be in position as I meant it to be. Vertically centered and aligned with other div 's content.

Here's my website look before adding the list child to the div: [image: BEFORE]
Here's after it: [image: AFTER]

As you can see, the `ABOUT US` has moved above a little.

Here's my JSFiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v85o0ppp/)

(I advise you to view the JSFiddle page at a 50% Zoom level to get a perspective of every div.)

Please provide a solution as to how I can prevent this from happening and also, if you'd like to help me additionally then tell me how to get a drop down on hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `line-height: 28px` to match the height of #navbar and the text will be aligned.

```
.nb_item
{
  display:inline-block;
  width:auto;
  padding:0px 10px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
  line-height: 28px; // Add
}
```

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/v85o0ppp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're putting the list *in* the div, so it's going to push the top part up of course since it's trying to vertically center.

One quick fix would be to add padding to the top of `.nb_item` to have it properly line up.

```
.nb_item {
    display:inline-block;
    width:auto;
    padding:6px 10px 0px 10px; /* added 6px padding to top */
    color:#FFFFFF;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Alternatively you could put your drop-down and drop-down header in different divs, but contained within the same one so you can still activate the drop-down on hover.

Comment: Is there a value central for vertical-align? Middle you mean?

Comment: @ManojKumar Just got rid of that part. It was from the original code.

Answer (score 0):

> Just change (`display: inline-block;`) in side (`.nb_item`) to either
>   (`display: inline-flex;`) or (`display: flex;`) also change (`padding:0;` to `padding:3px;`) inside `.header` and you can add `cursor: pointer;` inside `.nb_item:hover` to make pointer hand on hover.

**HTML Code:**

```
.html
{
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

body
{
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}

.header
{
  width: 80%;
  margin:auto;
  padding:3px;
  display:flex; 
}

#banner
{
  height: 200px;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

#navbar
{

  background-color: #70A5DA;
  height: 28px; 
}

.menu
{
  list-style-type:none;
}

.nb_item
{
    display: inline-flex;
    display: -webkit-inline-box;
    width:auto;
    padding:0px 10px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    margin:auto;
    justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: central;
}

.nb_item:hover
{
  color: #DDDDDD;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#comt_menu
{
  list-style-type:none;
}

#abtus_menu li
{
  list-style-type:none;
  display:none;

}

#rgstr_menu
{
  list-style-type:none;
}

#evnt_menu
{
  list-style-type:none;
}
.menu li
{
  display:inline;
}
```

**CSS Code:**

```
<div  class="header" id="banner"></div>
<div class="header" id="navbar">
        <div class="nb_item">HOME</div>
        <div class="nb_item">ABOUT US
        <ul id="abtus_menu">
                <li>LA MARTINIERE COLLEGE, LUCKNOW</li>
                <li>LA MARTINIERE MODEL UNITED NATIONS</li>
                <li>SECRETARIAT</li>
            </ul>
           </div>
        <div class="nb_item">REGISTER
            <!--<ul id="rgstr_menu">
                <li>INDIVIDUAL</li>
                <li>DELEGATION</li> 
            </ul>-->
        </div>
        <div class="nb_item">COMMITTEES
            <!--<ul id="comt_menu">
                <li>COMMITTEE 1</li>
                <li>COMMITTEE 2</li>
                <li>COMMITTEE 3</li>
                <li>COMMITTEE 4</li>
                <li>COMMITTEE 5</li>
                <li>COMMITTEE 6</li>
            </ul> -->
        </div>
        <div class="nb_item">RESOURCES</div>
        <div class="nb_item">EVENTS
        <!--<ul id="evnt_menu">
            <li>KEYNOTE SPEAKERS</li>
            <li>SOCIALS</li>
        </ul>-->
        </div>
        <div class="nb_item">SPONSORS</div>
        <div class="nb_item">CONTACT US</div>
</div>
```

If you have any qestion let me know

Comment: I know the benefits of using flex and inline-flex. But what happens is when I use it the space to the right of `ABOUT US` increases a lot. Please try it yourself and give me a solution for that. It looks like It is taking the with of the to-be drop down next to it.